# Perl Regex to Exclude Certain TLDs for Spamassassin

Tags: regex, perl, uri, tld, spamassassin

I am not at **all** able to code in Perl; so, what seems like a simple thing -- writing a regex to score all URIs that are **not** for "com" or "net" or "org" TLDs -- is apparently beyond my skills. Could someone kindly enlighten me?

As an example I want `https://foo.com.us/asdf?qwerty=123` to match and `ftp://madeup.kernel.org/path/to/some/tarball.tar.bz2` to not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex pattern

```
//(?:[a-z]+\.)*+(?!com/|net/|org/)
```

should do what you want. The slashes are part of the pattern, and are not delimiters

Here's a demonstration

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @urls = qw{
    https://foo.com.us/asdf?qwerty=123
    ftp://madeup.kernel.org/path/to/some/tarball.tar.bz2
};

for ( @urls ) {
    say m{//(?:[a-z]+\.)*+(?!com/|net/|org/)} ? 'match' : 'no match';
}
```

#### output

```
match
no match
```

Comment: I had tried  ...`(?!com|net|org)\/` without success. [Though typo failure is possible. :)]  Is there a rationale for including the final slash within the "or" group?

Comment: @justinzane: without that slash the regex would reject a name where the TLD *starts* with any of those strings. For instance, `www.batman.comics` would fail the test. Actually I've rewritten a little it so that the URL doesn't have to have a path

Comment: Nice use of [possessive greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#possessive)!  Note that the URL may not have a path, or there might be a port or query instead of a path.  I'd recommend the negative lookahead be `(?!(?:com|net|org)\b(?![.-]))` which includes a double negative to avoid a word break that is followed by a character allowed in a host name.  Also, the character class should be `[\w-]` to allow numbers and dashes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `URI` module to separate the host name from the rest of the URL

This example extracts only the final substring of the host name, so it will look at, say, `uk` from `bbc.co.uk`, but it should serve your purpose

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;

my @urls = qw{
    https://foo.com.us/asdf?qwerty=123
    ftp://madeup.kernel.org/path/to/some/tarball.tar.bz2
};

for my $url ( @urls ) {
    $url = URI->new($url);
    my $host = $url->host;
    my ($tld) = $host =~ /([^.]+)\z/;

    if ( $tld !~ /^(?com|net|org)\z/ ) {
        # non-standard TLD
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is going in a Spamassassin `local.cf` rule, I need a basic Perl regex without loading any other modules. The reason, I believe, is that the regex must be usable after being processed by re2c and compiled for "spamd".